# decode array with multiple json response in one api response in php

Tags: php, json, laravel, decode

I have a JSON output in my API response,
Like this:-

```
{ "m_time" : "2015-04-07 11:37:35", "id" : "30", "msg" : "Hai there 1"}
{ "m_time" : "2015-04-07 11:37:36", "id" : "31", "msg" : "Hai there 2"}
{ "m_time" : "2015-04-07 11:37:37", "id" : "32", "msg" : "Hai there 3"}
```

I have tried with JSON decode but it returns "null" &
I can't substr from response because it doesn't have any "," like this to separate each response (and not possible to change anything from API response)

How can I access each response from the data??

Comment: This simply is not valid JSON, so you will have to create your own parser logic for this. If you wrapped the whole thing in `[]`, and put a comma between the objects, then it can be parsed as JSON. (If it is absolutely sure that `} {` will never ever occur as part of the data, then you can simply replace those with `}, {`.)

Comment: I've changed the formatting markup of your question, which might be significant if it's now a more accurate representation: it is quite common to have a streaming format with a JSON document on each line, and in that case all you need to do is split the string into lines, then use a `foreach` loop to access each one.

Comment: I have done that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since JSON itself is not "streamable" (you can't add data on the end of a valid JSON document and still have a valid JSON document), there is a common format sometimes called "JSON lines": each line of data is a separate JSON document.

To process that data, all you need to do is split the string on newlines (e.g. using [explode](https://php.net/explode)), then use a `foreach` loop to pass *each line in turn* to `json_decode`.